# Error while trying to self reference a model in ember.js

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-web-api, ember.js

I'm trying to create a self-referenced property in a model, but I'm getting the following error:

> Error while processing route: index No model was found for 'menu' Error

Here is my model (menus.js):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({    
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  link: DS.attr('string'),
  isActive: DS.attr('boolean'),
  children: DS.hasMany('menus', { inverse: null }),
});
```

I'm trying to returning a list from a Web API. Here is my API JSON return:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test",
    "link": "index",
    "isActive": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Test 2",
        "link": "index",
        "isActive": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Test 2",
    "link": "index",
    "isActive": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Test 4 ",
        "link": "index",
        "isActive": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Test 5",
    "link": "index",
    "isActive": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Test 6",
        "link": "index",
        "isActive": false
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Test 7",
        "link": "index",
        "isActive": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call your models in singular form. So rename `model/menus.js` to `model/menu.js` and `DS.hasMany('menus', { inverse: null }),` with `DS.hasMany('menu', { inverse: null }),`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Lux! But now I'm getting this error when I call findAll method: "Assertion Failed: You can no longer pass a modelClass as the first argument to store.buildInternalModel. Pass modelName instead."

 return this.get('store').findAll('menu');

Comment: That error is not from that code. Probably you pass a model instead of a string to `findAll`.